# Matplotlib Not Plotting negative values: Extremely misleading

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, matplotlib

Matplotlib is not plotting negative values of my series making its plot extremely misleading.

Here is the series and plot:

```
df[df.SKU=='ProductB'].Sales.values
```

Output

```
array([ nan,  nan,  nan, -23.,
> 446., 361., 229., 219., 495., 278., 316.,
>        -50., 442., 459., 392., 381., 288., 240., 361., -45., 241., 328.,
>        233., 293., 387., 385., 442., -23., 376., 483., 301., 489., 487.,
>        464., 488.])
```

Plot: `plt.plot(df[df.SKU=='ProductB'].Sales.values)`
[image]

What is going on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code does plot negative values of your series.

```
# it's the same one you provided with additional '-2000.' value at the end
a = np.array([ np.nan,  np.nan,  np.nan, -23., 446., 361., 229., 219., 495., 278., 316., 
           -50., 442., 459., 392., 381., 288., 240., 361., -45., 241., 328.,
           233., 293., 387., 385., 442., -23., 376., 483., 301., 489., 487.,
           464., 488., -2000.])
```

### Try plotting this array using the same code:

[image: table](www.asd)[![enter image description here]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CyAvF.jpg)

---

So, as you can see, the problem is that your negative values are so close to zero that you can't really see them, given the ylim of your plot.